# open dict://“$word” stopped working for Chinese after upgrading to Big Sur

Tags: command-line, big-sur, dictionary

Not sure if this question is appropriate for this forum. If not, please let me know, and I will remove it (if I can).

I have a shell script `open dict://"$word"` that worked well in Catalina for both English and Chinese. It will open the **Dictionary.app** and look up the word for me.

**Problem**:

After upgrading to **Big Sur**, it now works only for English, not for Chinese anymore. If I try to look up a Chinese word, say, to execute `open dict://"中"`, it will give an error in the **Terminal.app**: `The file /Users/USERNAME/dict:/天 does not exist`. Looking up an English word, say `open dict://'hello'`, acts normally (i.e., it opens Dictionary.app and looks up "Hello" in the app). I can still look up Chinese words using Dictionary.app's interface.

I'm an amateur in programming. I don't know what I can try to solve this problem.

Any help appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with the `open` command when handling certain characters—for instance, `open http://www.google.com?q=中` gives a similar error message. It might be worth reporting this bug to Apple; in the meantime, you can use the following (admittedly less than elegant) workaround:

```js
osascript -l JavaScript -e "(a = Application.currentApplication()).includeStandardAdditions=true; a.openLocation('dict://' + encodeURIComponent('中'))"
```

This uses JavaScript for Automation to encode and open the URL, just as `open` does. To use the generic `$word` format, you would just make the following substitution:

```js
osascript -l JavaScript -e "(a = Application.currentApplication()).includeStandardAdditions=true; a.openLocation('dict://' + encodeURIComponent('$word'))"
```

Comment: Hello @aaplmath, Thanks a lot! I will seek to report it to Apple. Your solution works for me! Thank you very much!